# Facebook friend's friend count using graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it ok for a webservice which uses F-connect to store the friend count (NOT the friends list) from Facebook (or this is counted as a breach in privacy).
As the Facebook Graph API does not allow auth_tokens to be used to get such detail of friends if they are not registered to the webservice.

I have seen people recommending storing the friend count and showing it to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can help with this. I did some research on this topic.

Their policy states: *"You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any rights to such data."* The anwser to the FAQ 'How long can I store data' is as follows: *"We have deprecated our 24 hour data storage policy. You may now indefinitely cache data to improve your application's user experience."*

For the record, I am not an attorney, so Im looking at their statement from an IT perspective. If I read their statements (which basically says you may store anything received through the API), I would say it is ok to save the friend count.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok for a webservice which uses F-connect to store the friend count

We don't give out legal advice, consult an attorney. As always free legal advice is worthless, so even if we did tell you anything if it's legal, it's not trustworthy information.

> I have seen people recommending storing the friend count and showing it to others.

Facebook says this is ONLY ok if it serves a purpose for your application. Again, consult an attorney before you make any hard decisions.